# Stylus ParseError: Generating Font Icons

Tags: icons, webfonts, stylus

I'm trying to use Stylus to generate font icons in [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app), to also generate variables, but I'm getting a `parseError`:

> ParseError: icons.styl:930    926| for icon, i in $icons    927|
>     .icon-{icon}    928|        &:before    929|            content ${icon}
>
> unexpected "eos"

I am to generate `:before` and after `content` values for corresponding classes.  My loop is as follows:

```
for icon, i in $icons
    .icon-{icon}
        &:before
            content ${$icon}
```

I first assign each icon to its `content` value like so:

```
$icon-chrome = "\e829"

$icon-firefox = "\e82a"

$icon-IE = "\e82b"

$icon-opera = "\e82c"

$icon-safari = "\e82d"

$icon-IcoMoon = "\e82e"
```

Where `$icons` is equal to:

```
$icons = home2, home3, home4, office, newspaper, pencil2
```

How can I fix this `parseError` to correctly generate my font icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an interpolation to dynamically generate a variable name. For this purpose we have the `lookup` built-in function. For example:

```
$icons = home2, home3

$icon-home2 = '\e829'
$icon-home3 = '\e82a'

for icon, i in $icons
  .icon-{icon}
    &:before
      content lookup('$icon-' + icon)
```

But [hashes](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/hashes.html) are much better for this task.